# Flutter - Getx Value updates only after hot reload

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, state-management, flutter-state

Consider the following code

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<HomeController>(
        init: HomeController(),
        builder: (controller) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  phoneWidget(),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: controller.formController,
                  ),

                  ElevatedButton(onPressed: ()=> controller.clearForm(), child: const Text('Clear'))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  Widget phoneWidget() {
    final HomeController _controller = Get.find();
    return  Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.amber,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
        ),
        child: IntlPhoneField(  // the widget in question
          controller:_controller.secondController ,
          showCountryFlag: false,
          iconPosition: IconPosition.trailing,
          autoValidate: false,
          initialValue: _controller.initialPhoneNumber,
          initialCountryCode: _controller.initialCountryCode,
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

In the above i have a widget. which I'm setting initial values at init on controller.

```
class HomeController extends GetxController{

  final _intialCountryCode = ''.obs;
  String get initialCountryCode => _intialCountryCode.value;

  final _initialPhoneNumber = ''.obs;
  String get initialPhoneNumber => _initialPhoneNumber.value;

  final formController = TextEditingController();
  final secondController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    _intialCountryCode('IN');
    _initialPhoneNumber('123457788');
    formController.text = "TEST";
    secondController.text = '1234944627';
  }

  clearForm(){
    formController.clear();
    secondController.clear();
    secondController.text = '123349526';
  }
}
```

I'm using Getx for my application. I'm assigning values for this widget on init. What I'm expecting is to the widget shows the initial value when the screen is loaded. How ever the changes are not reflected on the widget, instead if I hot-reload, the changes are updated on the widget. I have tried wrapping the widget with Obx. but the results are same. The changes are made only after  hot reload. What causes this? Why does the widget only updates after hot reload? How can i resolve this properly

Comment: Can you show more of the code in the Controller side?

Comment: @PandaCórdoba updated with controller code

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly you want to do with this piece of code because I can se a lot of things that can be changed for the better, that is unless you want to actually do it like this which I don't really see why you would do that. And also a picture of the app so that we can have a better understanding of what you want to do.

Comment: @PandaCórdoba the widget have some iniitial values to showcase like phonenumber and countrycode.  So on init im assigning the values that needed to show on the widget to obs variables.  i'm expecting these variables should be updated whenever the screen loads (ie phone number and country code). The values are updated on the widget only after hot reload

Comment: What I'm asking is what is the idea of your application for this screen on what it will do so that I can refer you to a source code or refactore tore your code

Comment: @PandaCórdoba the screen is a userform. which shows signed in users details. the issue i'm facing is  ui updates only after hot reload. Im expecting the ui should show user data.

Comment: cant understand the problem .please explain it more simplified and in brief. Share screenshots also what you wanted to do so or what problem you having it will help us to understand @FebinJohnson

Answer (score 1):

```
class HomeController extends GetxController{

  final _intialCountryCode = ''.obs;
  String get initialCountryCode => _intialCountryCode.value;

  final _initialPhoneNumber = ''.obs;
  String get initialPhoneNumber => _initialPhoneNumber.value;

  final formController = TextEditingController().obs;
  final secondController = TextEditingController().obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    _intialCountryCode('IN');
    _initialPhoneNumber('123457788');
    formController.text = "TEST";
    secondController.text = '1234944627';
  }

  clearForm(){
    formController.clear();
    secondController.clear();
    secondController.text = '1234944627';
  }
}
```

```
GetX<HomeController>(
        init: HomeController(),
        builder: (controller) {
```

try adding this changes and see if it works